# Geodesic equation without metricity

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

If we relax the metricity condition, what change will be seen in the geodesic equation ? For instance, when the torsionless connection is relaxed while keeping the metricity intact, we see that the original geodesic equation is augmented with the contorsion tensor. Similarly what other changes can be expected if the metricity is also relaxed. I have heard that geometry without non-metricity is non-Riemannian. Is it true ?

Comment: What do you mean by change geodesic equation ? We only need connection on tangent bundle to define covariant derivative, having this in principle we know what the Christoffel symbol on charts and by that the geodesic equation having the same form, only this time it is not determined by metric since we don't have one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have heard that geometry without non-metricity is non-Riemannian. Is it true ?

Yes, this is true. The covariant derivative of the metric tensor $g_{\alpha \beta}$, $\nabla g_{\alpha \beta}$ vanished in the case of Riemannian Geometry whereas if it doesn't, and denoting it by 
$$\Xi_{\mu \alpha \beta} = \nabla_{\mu} g_{\alpha \beta}$$

is clearly a tensor field of order $3$ and measures the rate of change of the components of the metric along the flow of the vector field.

As an example, consider a spacetime including torsion that will generate a different Elecromagentic field, and test particles send in such conditions will deviate from the trajectory we would expect without torsion. It will affect the conservation of scalar quantities along geodesics, for instance, in the case of the mass

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dp^2}{d\lambda}&=& \frac{d(g_{\mu\nu} p^\mu p^\nu)}{d\lambda} \\
&=& m^2 u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha (g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu)\\
&=& m^2 u^\alpha (\Xi_{\alpha\mu\nu} u^\mu u^\nu + g_{\mu\nu} u^\nu \nabla_\alpha u^\mu + g_{\mu\nu} u^\mu \nabla_\alpha u^\nu)
\end{eqnarray}

for geodesics, $u^\alpha \nabla_\alpha u^\mu = 0$, leaving

\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{dp^2}{d\lambda}&=& m^2  \Xi_{\alpha\mu\nu} u^\alpha u^\mu u^\nu 
\end{eqnarray}

Meaning a free particle would change mass along its trajectory.

Comment: So the geodesic equation is left un augmented ? Unlike the case of the connection with torsion where it gets augmented by the contorsion tensor.

Comment: The contorsion tensor only appears if you split your Christoffel symbols into symmetric and antisymmetric parts (in the lower indices). Otherwise the geodesic equation looks the same as always, only that the sum over the lower indices is not necessarily symmetric.

Comment: @S.Surace In physics, the geodesic equation is derived using Euler-Lagrange equations I.e. by extremising the proper time. What changes will occur if we tried to do it for non-riemannian geometries ?

Comment: The proper time/length extremization only makes sense when the connection is compatible with a metric used to measure length/time, i.e. if it satisfies the metricity condition or in other words, the metric is constant wrt. the connection. The more general view of geodesics is that of a "straight line" i.e. one along which the velocity vector field is parallel.